# Is there any way to get mode of column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

here is the table input

[image]

and desired output

[image]

basically, I want to get the mode value which means the most frequent value of first_hour and last_hour grouped by month and id. if frequent values occur then take this else make an alternate decision.

Is there any way to get the result? Please kindly help me

Comment: Your description is much too unclear. Please explain in detail the whole logic how/why to get the result you've shown.

Comment: 'most frequent' <> 'mode'.

Comment: what i am meaning that 'most re-appearing  values'

Answer (score 0):

I tried something. It works but try by yourself to improvise the solution

```
select q1.id, q1.month, q1.first_hour, q2.last_hour from (select id,month, first_hour, max(freq) first_hour_freq from 

(select id,month, count(first_hour) freq, first_hour from mytable 
 group by id, month, first_hour) as innerQuery

group by id,month) q1

inner join 

(select id,month, last_hour, max(freq) last_hour_hour_freq from 

(select id,month, count(last_hour) freq, last_hour from mytable 
 group by id, month, last_hour) as innerQuery

group by id,month) q2

on q1.id = q2.id and q1.month=q2.month
```

Tested in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfdc28/15